# Open file with relative path

Tags: python, windows, path

I'm trying to open file in relative location:

```
import time, os
day=time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
month=time.strftime("%m")
filename=time.strftime("%Y%m%d")


logs_dir = os.path.dirname('C:\Users\user1\Desktop\folder\main\Logs') 
rel_path = '\'+month+'\'+filename+'.txt'
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
file = open(abs_file_path, 'r')
```

I couldn't get the second line right with variables and backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u` has special meaning in a Python string literal; it denotes a Unicode character.  So does `\f`, which denotes a formfeed.

You will need to use a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
logs_dir = os.path.dirname(r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\folder\main\Logs')
```

or forwardslashes:

```
logs_dir = os.path.dirname('C:/Users/user1/Desktop/folder/main/Logs')
```

in order to keep Python from interpreting them as such. You could also double every backslash:

```
logs_dir = os.path.dirname('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\folder\\main\\Logs')
```

but that is rather tedious.

---

Also, you need to double the backslash for every `'\'` since string literals cannot end in a single `\`.  But this is not a very robust solution.  A better approach for building paths is to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
rel_path = os.path.join('\\', month, filename + '.txt')
```

Then, you can replace every `'\\'` with [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep) as @helloV said in his answer.  This will ensure that your code creates proper-looking paths on both Windows and *nix systems.

Comment: You don't need the `'\\'` between `month` and `filename` in the call to `os.path.join`.

Comment: Thanks, I was just copying the OP's code and missed that.

Comment: Thanks! I had to add a double backslashes at the end `logs_dir = os.path.dirname(r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\folder\main\Logs\\')` and all worked perfect!

Comment: Try to avoid forward slashes.  They're OK in this particular context, but not always, and it's a dangerous habit to get into.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, can you give an example of a context where they would not be OK?

Comment: @Kevin: the canonical example is when you are dealing with paths longer than 256 characters, or a [path that contains a volume GUID rather than using a drive letter.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17099136/886887)  But it also doesn't work reliably on the command line; the GUI shell (including, presumably, at least some shell-based APIs) doesn't seem to accept them; and I believe I've seen reports of a few other API calls that don't accept them, though I don't recall the details.

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.sep` instead of '\', to avoid escaping issues.

Try:

```
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, month, filename) + '.txt'
```